# how to query this complex array arrtibue in the mongoose or mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Now I am working on a bus tracking program, in which I use mongodb to store the static bus schedule, in addition to the schedule, I can receive a real time bus arrival and departure event, the event stream includes the arrival/departure time, current station and next station. However the event stream doesn't tell me the bus number, that makes it tricky to track the bus directly. But as I know when and where the bus should be according to the schedule, I can use the schedule to induce the bus number and finally track the bus.

my mongodb database stores the schedules of buses, the schema is 
{ busNumber:'019191', timeline:[{'station':'station 1', 'time': '9:20' },{'station':'station 2', 'time': '9:30' }, ................  ] }.

My real time events has arrival/departure time, current station and next station.

But the problem is how can I do the query the array using the mongodb and mongoose, my current query is to find the schedule with that station,

```
Schedule.findOne({'timeline.station ': current_station}, function(err, sche) {
```

and Then loop over all the time to find the bus happen to be at that moment and place

```
schedule.time.forEach(function(t) {
  if (t.time== currenttime && t.station == currentstation) {
    thing = t;
  }
});
```

I guess there must be a way to do it just by query and without ugly loop, so I can query to find the array element whose time and place equals to current situation, moreover station of the next array element also equals to the next_station in real time bus event

Answer (score 0):

```
Schedule.findOne({ 'timeline.station': current_station, 'timeline.time' : current_time }, function(err, sche) { .... );
```

Also, to handle for deviation in times both ahead or behind, query and design around time-frames. By using $gt,$gte,$lt and $lte you can specify the time-frame you would like to query (for a cookie-cutter solution, look into using Mongo's Date type). [Query-operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)